# Dynamically create custom field in C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, angularjs, sql-server

I am using sql server database, entity frame work, c# and angular js for my application. Now I need custom field to create an item definition. Suppose I have item chair which has some field field1, field2, field3 as well as table which has some field field1, field2, fiel3d, field4, field5. field4, field5 are extra whose are not defined into table or my c# object. **How can I create, delete, update and get as an item record field?**

**EAV** concept is very interesting, but it has some problem to show stock item report. Please give me any idea or solution for custom field create. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what you're asking. Can you provide more details?

Comment: @dman2306, dynamically add column to sql table as well as c# object. How can i do that?

Comment: You want to add columns to a SQL table on the fly? I can't imagine why you would ever want to do that. In 20 years of db programming I've never had a reason to do that. My guess is this is an XY problem. Instead of asking about a hypothetical solution, describe the actual problem you're trying to solve because I suspect your solution of a dynamic table is the wrong solution.

Comment: @dman2306, you know many item are exist to our world. its item has own different definition, such furniture and mobile item are defined their own various attribute. I want to store all of item of world into one table. how can i defined that table which will cover all of item attribute.

Comment: In the world of relational databases you wouldn't. You have a table of chairs, a table of dogs, a table of trucks, etc. Relational databases are designed around fixed table schemas. if you want to store it in a single table where each row has different properties then you'd need to add an xml or json column to store that data. Honestly though it sounds like SQL isn't the right database type for what you're doing. Perhaps consider a nosql alternative.